# nested state did not update having parsing error

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update my nested state in context but it's having an problem about the parsing error.

Here is my `GlobalState.js`:

```
const [currentUser, setUser] = useState(props.serverUserData);


  const updateProfileImage = (picture) => {
    console.log('New Profile Image', picture);
    setUser({...currentUser, currentUser.picture: picture});
    console.log('currentUser2', currentUser.picture);
  };
```

This function help user upload their profile image but after the upload success the image didn't change until user have to log out and log back in. So I decided to create an updateProfileImage function in context that user don't need to log out and log back in to see image change.

```
  const uploadImage = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", imageSelected);
    formData.append("id", id);

    axios
      .post("/api/v1/users/upload/image", formData, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        updateUserAvatar(response.data.data.imageUrl);
      });
  };
```

How can I do nested state the correct way?

```
console.log(currentUser):

{id: "a19cac5c-ea25-4c9c-b1d9-5d6e464869ed", name: "Nhan Nguyen", email: "nhan13574@gmail.com", publicId: "Nh1615314435848", picture: "http://res.cloudinary.com/teammateme/image/upload/v1617173805/kqq7bnsujegvg2sgldox.svg", …}
email: "nhan13574@gmail.com"
id: "a19cac5c-ea25-4c9c-b1d9-5d6e464869ed"
isSessionValid: true
name: "Nhan Nguyen"
picture: "http://res.cloudinary.com/teammateme/image/upload/v1617173805/kqq7bnsujegvg2sgldox.svg"
publicId: "Nh1615314435848"
__proto__: Object
```

GlobalContext.js:

```
import React from "react";

const globalStateDefaults = {
  modals: {
    isAuthModalOpen: false,
    modalToDisplay: "signup",
    toggleModal: () => {},
    setModalToDisplay: () => {}
  },
  user: undefined,
  pageName: undefined,
  loading: false,
  teamProfileId: "",
  userProfileId: ""
};

export const GlobalContext = React.createContext(globalStateDefaults);
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem? I really appreciate it.

Comment: can you share the state structure?

Comment: @amreshk005 just added it in my post

Answer (score 0):

So in state parsing

```
setUser({...currentUser, currentUser.picture: picture});
```

instead of this one you can try this

```
setUser({...currentUser, picture: picture});
```

Comment: it seems like my currentUser.picture still didnt update

Comment: the way you have updated the state is wrong.

Comment: You can console your state in render method.